# identifying low information features with $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

On this site [TEXT CLASSIFICATION FOR SENTIMENT ANALYSIS – ELIMINATE LOW INFORMATION FEATURES](http://streamhacker.com/2010/06/16/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-eliminate-low-information-features/), low information features are identified by using the `BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq` function of NLTK.

My question: What does $\chi^2$ have to do with this? How are the low information features identified by using $\chi^2$? I only know $\chi^2$ from independence tests.

I am only just beginning with machine learning, so keep it simple :)

Comment: Without even looking at the link, why would you be surprised to see the chi-squared distribution? Aren't questions about information questions about dependency between variables?

Comment: Well, as I said, I know chi² from independence testing and I have seen that it is used to find bigrams, but I not sure which role it plays. How is chi squared used to measure if something is a low information feature? With bigrams I can kinda see it: I would guess it is used to see if two words occur as a pair so often that it cannot be coincidence... but I have no idea whether thats true. Also, I am a beginner in machine learning and not the best at maths.